# When I swipe to open item, it auto closed on HTC device (Android 5.1) : Using AndroidSwipeLayout library of daimajia

Tags: android, android-layout, swipe

When I swipe to open an item, it auto closed on HTC device (Android 5.1). On other devices, it is working fine. I am using AndroidSwipeLayout library of daimajia (version 1.2.0). Any help is well appreciated

Comment: What's your logcat showing?